# WebView Animation issue on Android

Tags: android, webview, slider, cordova, swipe

I am developing an Android application using html, css and javascript.
my application depends on Phonegap framework.
The application consists of a quite number of local pages. In the
application I am trying to handle swipe gesture event on the Android
mobile and move the pages depending on the swipe direction. I.e if the
user swipes to the left the application must call the previous page,
then if the user swipes to the right then the application will forward
the user to the next page.

I can do that using native java for android. but the problem is,
during the calling for the page I'm doing a slide effect for the
requested page. but what happens is the current page takes the slide
effect not the requested page, that is after the slide effect
finishes, the requested page appears :(
I am looking for a mechanism for making the effect affects the
requested local page not the current page. I tried delaying the
animation duration but it became too much slow, so it became boring
and btw failed to achieve that.

I hope that you help me in this problem, or suggesting to me any
approach or mechanism to achieve that effect.

Here is my code:

```
public class App extends DroidGap {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
    private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    View.OnTouchListener gestureListener;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new MyGestureDetector());

        gestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        };
      super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

    }

    class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            try {

                if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                    return false;
                // right to left swipe
                if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {


                appView.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide_left));
                appView.goBack();
                }  else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                     appView.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide_right_in));
                  appView.goForward();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // nothing
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent e){
        super.dispatchTouchEvent(e);
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some code to explain what you have done till now..

Comment: I've updated the post and included the source code for handling the swipe event and what I did for going back and forward

Comment: Never dump the code as it is. Remove the unwanted/commented part and keep it tidy.

Comment: @Tushar Vengurlekar am sorry for this mistake, 
kindly find it is now more tidy and readable :) 
Hope you could help me in this problem

Comment: How are you swiping the pages, using Viewlipper?

Comment: I've handled the swipe event
then checked whether it is to the right or to the left,
depending on that called the method goForward() or goBack() in the view. 
I did not use viewflipper.

Comment: It is not clear still to me how you are sliding. What exactly the methods goForward() or goBack() are doing. From whatever I understand you are attaching the animation to the wrong view it should be for the view appearing next. Unless it is not clear how you are getting next view, I can't suggest more.

Comment: goBack() and goForward() method are in the WebView class, they do the same work as history.back() and history.forward() in javascript, i.e they redirect the page back and forward depending on the history of pages visited during the browsing. 
as for animation they are an xml file attached to the project they are responsible for doing the animation, the animation works correctly for sliding left or right, but the problem it does it for the current view not the prev one or the next one. 
I hope it is now clear for you

Comment: Hey @anas you have asked a nice question.Can i just get the code for your animation file plz.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding animation before the event goBack() and goForward() causing mismatch. I would suggest you to create a custom webview and override the two methods. Somewhat as shown below.

```
    public class mywebView extends WebView{

    public mywebView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void goBack(){

    }

    @Override
    public void goForward(){            
    }       
}
```

Dont miss the keyword `@Override`. Now within these overridden methods you can add the code for animation. Hope this helps.

Comment: I've tried to call the animation after calling the goBack() or goForward() but the same thing happens the current page takes the effect not the back or forward one.

Comment: yes it will not work that way. try the alternative I suggested above.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, 
Actually, the methods goBack and goForward are inside an initialized object contained via the classs provided by phonegap, so I cannot override it :(

Answer (score 0):

This is android  library functions.so use  android.R.anim.fade_out instead of R.anim.fade_out

' Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(),android.R.anim.fade_out)
   MainActivity.webview.startAnimation(anim);'

I hope this is helpful for you.....